# Class Method Example in objective -c

Tags: iphone

can anyone tell me how to create a class method and using that how can we share an object DATA in all classes......?

Comment: when you say sharing object data in all classes... are you saying that there will be a static variable as a member of the class, value of which will be shared among all the instances??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-(returnType)methodName;`  --> this is your normal object method

`+(returnType)methodName;`  --> this will be your class method

`[Classname methodName]`    --> This is how you will call the class method

Answer (score 1):

A class method has no state therefore can't do what you're asking for. You want to create a singleton object and pass that around. Check out [Singletons, AppDelegates and top-level data](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) for a discussion of singletons and a handy macro for automatically creating them.